# Integrating python PDF generator library with Angular

Tags: python, angular, pdf, external

What is the approach to integrate external python PDF generator library with Angular. Please explain with example.

Comment: Hey Rajnish, welcome to SO. You going to need to be a lot more specific in order for people to be able to help you. How are you trying to integrate them? Which PDF libraries have you looked at? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Flask or Django server side Frameworks given by Python as the backend of
   your application
2. Use the reportlab library given in Django if Django is used or use libraries like PyPDF
   and call your custom PDF creation function that you will do using pyPDF in your server
   side api endpoints.
3. Now sending the file back to the client: for Flask it has an inbuilt modules like
   send_file, send_from_directory, safe_join etc. Check out the Flask documentation. Now
   if you use Django, Django has its own module also called send_file. Check out the docs.

I hope it will be helpful for you